# Why is Git undoing the rebase process when I'm checking out to the most recent commit?

Tags: git, rebase

Dears,

I want to delete a very old commit on git repo, but after execute the rebase process and making a checkout to the last branch of my repository the proccess is being undone. So, this is what I'm doing:

```
git log
abcdef - Last repo commit (master)
...
... # many many commits
...
222333 - A
111222 - B <-- I want to delete this
000111 - C
```

Change the HEAD, just for readability:

```
git checkout 222333
git rebase -i 000111
```

At this point, I edit the todo shown by rebase, changing the text from pick to edit.

```
pick 222333 - A
pick 111222 - B (change to edit)
pick 000111 - C
```

Now I'm making modifications on file content inside the commit. After this:

```
git add .
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

After all, when inspecting using `git log` or `gitk` everything is ok. But when I return to master `git checkout master`, all the proccess is undone, when inspecting again! Does anyone know why?

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Git 2.31.1.windows.1

Comment: What's the name of your active branch at the end of the rebase ?

Comment: What do the first lines in `git reflog` say ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line, which you say you're doing "just for readability":

```
git checkout 222333
```

This puts you in "detached head" state: your working copy is on that revision, *and not on any branch*.

While in that state, you rebase some commits, which creates a new history, made up of new commits. Normally, this would also move the current branch pointer to point at those new commits, but you *don't have a current branch*, so no pointers are moved.

Finally, you run `git checkout master` which switches to the branch called "master". A branch is just a pointer, and this one doesn't point at the new commits which `git rebase` generated, it points wherever it pointed before. The newly created commits are left "orphaned" with no branches pointing at them.

There's another problem, too: commits in git are *immutable*, so any edit to history has to create new commits *from that point forward*. The "many many commits" you show in your log summary *all need to be rewritten*, so they all need to be listed in the interactive rebase todo list.

(If you've watched enough sci-fi films, "changing history" in git is like the form of time travel where you don't change your own past, you create a parallel universe with a different past, and a correspondingly different future.)

So forget about making it "readable", and just run this:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i 000111
```

All the many many lines labelled "pick" are the ones that are going to be re-created; just scroll past them and delete the one which you want to *not* re-create.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP :). I didn’t know that “detached” cause this kind of effect.

Comment: @HelioJunior It will probably help to keep in mind that a branch in git _only points at the latest commit_, and commits in its history don't "belong to" the branch in any way. So whenever you reference a commit by its hash, git has no idea what branch you might be thinking about.

Comment: I would like to learn more about the effects of "detached head" state. If you recommend me, I will thank you.

Comment: @HelioJunior Simple advice is just don't do _anything_ when you're in a "detached head" state other than look at files. Pretty much anything you do is going to be less confusing if you're on some branch, even if it's a branch called "i-dont-know-what-im-doing".